# Passing consolidated config file to native sdks

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-scripts

I'm working on a react native module that has native iOS & android sdks, the sdks have their own respective config files that I'd like to consolidate into one in react native but I'm having a hard time finding best practices on how to do that. I can find plenty of ways of handling config in react native but not much on passing that down to native code.

I think ideally I have a script that copies a file from the root of the project the module is installed in to wherever it might live natively but I'm not finding anything specific on pre scripts that might run when `react native start` is ran.

It's not the end of the world to update the sdks but I'm exploring options before going that route.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!